# Is Something-Aware a design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

In the Struts2 interceptor package, we can see many XxxAware interfaces, like `ApplicationAware`, `CookieAware`, and so on.

In the Spring framework, `ApplicationContextAware`, `BeanFactoryAware`, and other examples can be seen as well.

I also follow this design concept to implement my framework. Is this a kind of design pattern? Does it have a name?

Answer (score 3):

The design pattern is still Dependency Injection and IOC.  The marker interfaces are just a clunky language-version specific way of implementing it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like maybe it's using the Observer pattern.